# Working with times in a sports app C#

Tags: c#, time

I am creating an app that can calculate times on a rowing machine as a little experiment for myself. You can either calculate a split (how long it takes to do 500 m), the total distance or total time using these equations...

> distance = (time/split) * 500
>
> split = 500 * (time/distance)
>
> time = split * (distance/500)

distance is shown in meters (thats the easy bit) but for the two times i want to show it in the format mm:ss.fff(e.g: 2:00.00).

**My first problem is** that when i try to parse the entered string using `TimeSpan parsedSplitTime = TimeSpan.ParseExact(splitInput, "c", provider);` It requires the string...

A) To have a 0 in front of the minute, so it cant be entered as 2:00.00 and has to be entered as 02:00.00 which for ease of use is not very good and i cant just add that to the string in problem B as the user may enter 12mins for example.

B) I have to add "0.00:" to the front of the string for it to format

`string splitInput = "0.00:" + enteredSplit.Text;`

**My second problem is** that i dont think the way i do my calculations is very efficient and whe i convert it back to a string to put in a text box it is not formatted how i wanted it to be (see beginning of post)

This is the code i use to work out the total time.

```
string splitInput = "0.00:" + enteredSplit.Text;
TimeSpan parsedSplitTime = TimeSpan.ParseExact(splitInput, "c", provider);

double distanceAsInt = Int64.Parse(enteredDistance.Text);
distanceAsInt = distanceAsInt / 500;

double totalTimeMilli = parsedSplitTime.TotalMilliseconds * distanceAsInt;

TimeSpan timeReadable = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(totalTimeMilli).;
string enteredTimeAsString = timeReadable.ToString();
enteredTimeAsString = enteredTimeAsString.Remove(0, 3);
enteredTime.Text = $"{enteredTimeAsString}.00";
```

Thanks for all help in advance! And if you want any more details just comment and ill add it under here!

The input is put in manually but i have hinted it to be put in like 0:00.00 but you currently have to do 00:00.00 and i want output to be 0:00.00

provider definition `CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;`

it is entered as a string

Comment: Can you please show examples of expected input and output? Are users entering the values in manually? What are they actually typing in the text box? Formatting input is not too hard, but it's not clear what the original data looks like.  Also, you should really limit your question to a single question, not multiple related questions.

Comment: Also, you should show the definition of `provider`

Comment: @RufusL i have now edited my post to include both of what you asked for.

Comment: _The input is put in manually but i have hinted it to be put in like 0:00.00 but you currently have to do 00:00.00 and i want output to be 0:00.00 "_ - The input and output of a Timespan are quite different - you can take input in any format you want and then output it in a different format.

Comment: So you don't want to allow the user to enter the `days` or `hours` portion of the time, just minutes, seconds, and milliseconds. Is that right?

Comment: @stuartd well the input time goes through the calculation so split-input * (distance-input/500)

Comment: @RufusL correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this would be to parse your input first (into minutes, seconds, and milliseconds), and create a `TimeSpan` object from that input using the constructor that takes days, hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds.

Since we don't know the exact format of the input, we can use `string.Split` to divide the string into the parts we know about, using the `:` character as a delimeter:

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a timespan from an input string that specifies minutes:seconds
/// </summary>
/// <param name="input">"minutes:seconds", where seconds can be a double</param>
/// <returns>Timespan representation of the input string</returns>
private static TimeSpan ParseMinSecMS(string input)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(input))
        throw new ArgumentException("input cannot be null, empty, or whitespace");

    var parts = input.Split(':');
    var minutes = "00";
    string seconds;
    if (parts.Length > 1)
    {
        minutes = parts[0].PadLeft(2, '0');
        seconds = parts[1].PadRight(1, '0');
    }
    else
    {
        seconds = parts[0].PadRight(1, '0');
    }

    return TimeSpan.Parse($"0.00:{minutes}:{seconds}");
}
```

Then you can use this method like so:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var inputs = new List<string>
    {
        "2",
        "2.3",
        "1:2.34",
        "25:32.908",
        "1.2345"
    };

    foreach (var input in inputs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ParseMinSecMS(input).ToString("mm\\:ss\\.ffff"));
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks this is great but i have one question. would i put this also through the parse? ` TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(totalTimeMilli).;`

Comment: as i convert it to milliseconds for the calculations but then i need to put the answer to the calculation back into time but when i use `FromMillisenconds it formats it wrong again. @RufusL

Comment: Updated my answer since I was treating the fractional seconds as `seconds.milliseconds`, which wasn't correct.

Comment: @euandeas You can use the `TotalMilliseconds` of the returned `TimeSpan` to do your calculations, and then you can use a [Custom TimeSpan Format String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-timespan-format-strings) to output the results. For a more specific answer, please separate that part out into a new question. This is addressing your first question (you should only have one question per question).

Comment: i was using the code from your previous answer before it was edited and when it puts the split mins seconds and milliseconds into a timespan it puts a 0 in front of the millisecond. do you know why?

Comment: It was treating the fractional portion of the seconds as milliseconds, which isn't correct. `2.1` seconds is not `2 seconds, 1 millisecond`, it's `2 seconds, 100 milliseconds`. That's why I changed the answer... :)

Comment: ah thanks. in the ouput in your post it shows one more 3 at the beginning than it should is this because of the no capitalized f?

Comment: Oh it might be! Will have to check that later, I'm away now

Comment: Thanks for your help this works perfectly! i fixed the f thing and it was that one was lower case!

Comment: I have one question just to make sure i fully understand the method you created for me. what does it do with the milli seconds ?. nvm i think i get it now